# Particle Falloff value

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I have a setup where I have a plane emitting particles (Simulation Nodes) and I wish to have two objects that are placed on either side of the particle emitter to control the falloff size of the particles on each end of the emitter. Here is an example of my efforts so far.

[image]

My question is: Can I have the particles remain at a zero size once the cubes that effect the size pass them, travelling towards the centre of the particle emitter?

Eventually I will have the particles moving but for now I just need to see if my question is possible berfore moving forward.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you were generating negative scales, so I switched the sign in the Map Range: To Max, to spare you some problems further down the road.

This setup will check if the currently evaluated value is smaller than the previous one, and only in then will override the previous state:

[image]

Your setup becomes:

[image]

[image]

And here's what's you're probably after:

[image]

[image]